# How do I join an array with an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have an array of objects named Indicators and an Array named Departments

For every indicator I’m supposed to add each department. So if there are 4 departments, there should be 4 indicators with the same index but with different departments. How can I achieve this?

EDIT:
Here is my code

```
     let arrDepartment = []
                         this.DepartmentIR.forEach(e=>{
                            arrDepartment.push(e.Department)
                         })
                     
                        this.RisksIndicatorsIR.forEach(e=>{   
                            let x = {...e}
                            x.Departments = arrDepartment    
                            console.log(x)
                        })
                    })
```

Comment: Post your solution what you've tried first.

Comment: I posted my code. Thanks.

Comment: Hey cjdy13, I posted 2 solutions with all departments on each indicator and 1 solution with only 1 department on each indicator. Please click the green checkmark to the left of upvote if this helped you.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const departments = [
  "department1",
  "department2",
  "department3",
  "department4"
];
const indicators = [
  { name: "indicators1", id: 95 },
  { name: "indicators2", id: 92 },
  { name: "indicators3", id: 93 },
  { name: "indicators4", id: 94 }
];

// Solution with forEach - all departments as key on each indicator
const newIndicators = [];
indicators.forEach((x) =>
  newIndicators.push({ ...x, departments: departments })
);

console.log("Solution with forEach", newIndicators);

// Solution with Reduce - all departments as key on each indicator
const newIndicatorsArr = indicators.reduce((acc, x) => {
  acc.push({ ...x, departments: departments });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log("Solution with Reduce", newIndicatorsArr);

// Solution if you want 1 department per indicator
const oneDepartmentPerIndicator = indicators.reduce((acc, x, i) => {
  acc.push({ ...x, departments: departments[i] });
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log("Solution with 1 department per indicator", newIndicatorsArr);
```